# How do I have a single select and a multiselect in my tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in my cellForRowAt Im inflating my xib and setting its content:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row]
    let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableCellTap(_:cell:)))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.checkBox.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    cell.checkBox.boxType = .circle

    cell.checkBox.markType = .radio
    cell.checkBox.cornerRadius = 0
    cell.checkBox.stateChangeAnimation = .expand(.fill)

    if (indexPath.row == selectedIndex){
        cell.checkBox.checkState = .checked
    }else{
        cell.checkBox.checkState = .unchecked
    }



    return cell
}
```

Then Im setting my deselect and select values

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.checkBox.checkState = .checked
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.checkBox.checkState = .unchecked
}
```

I need a sense of direction in how i can make it select and deselect the same row and update my xib file checkbox?
m13checkbox is being used
when i click on the cell for the first time it selects it but when i click on the same cell again it does not call it and does nothing until a loop a completed in the checkboxes

Comment: have u set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`

Comment: You can check it from: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: is there a swift version?

Comment: my xib file contains my check button / radio button

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `didDeselectRowAt`, you can achieve the same functionality by checking if the radio button is checked in your `didSelectRowAt`.
If the radio button is checked, simply uncheck it and vice versa.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if(cell.checkBox.isChecked){
        cell.checkBox.checkState = .unchecked   
    }else{
        cell.checkBox.checkState = .checked 
    }

}
```

Comment: m13 checkbox does not have a bool value for isChecked?

Comment: you can add a bool property in tableViewCell for checking if the cell is selected or not. every time you are selecting the radioBox, you can update the bool variable.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has already given very good sample code for that on its website,
you can check at:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html